# Laplacian of Fourier-like function

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, laplacian

The question that follows has to do with the effects of a turbulent atmosphere on wave propagation. The structure function, $D(\vec{r})$, which is defined as,

\begin{equation}
D(\vec{r}) = \left\langle \left[ n(\vec{x} - \vec{d}) - n(\vec{x}) \right]^2\right\rangle \, ,
\end{equation}

and is what our instruments observe, is related to the power spectrum, $\Phi(\vec{k})$, thought

\begin{equation}
 D(\vec{r}) = 2 \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \Phi(\vec{k}) [1 - \cos(\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r})] d^3k \label{1}\tag{1}
\end{equation}

According to the textbook I am reading on the topic, I can obtain the inverse of \eqref{1} by operating with a Laplacian on it, which results in,

\begin{equation}
\Phi(\vec{k}) = \frac{1}{16 \pi^3 k^2} \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \cos(\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}) \, \Delta D(\vec{r}) d^3r  \label{2}\tag{2}
\end{equation}

where $\Delta$ is the Laplace operator. Under the assumption of a locally isotropic field, I can introduce spherical coordinates  and integrate over the angular variables to obtain

\begin{equation}
\Phi(k) = \frac{1}{4 \pi^2 k^2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(kr)}{kr} \frac{d}{dr} \left[ r^2 \frac{d}{dr} D(r) \right] dr \label{3}\tag{3}
\end{equation}

**Objective:** Derive the equivalent formula to Eq. \eqref{3} in the 2D case.

**Question:** My calculus is a bit rusty so I am struggling to work out how to derive Eq. \eqref{2} from Eq. \eqref{1}. I assume Eq. \eqref{2} above is for a 3D field and the relation will be different in the 2D case (correct me if I am wrong on this). If I have Eq. \eqref{2} in 2D, I can easily derive  Eq. \eqref{2} by introducing polar coordinates.